# How to catch this error and represent the view controller that was attempted to be presented

Tags: ios, swift

> Warning: Attempt to present HolaViewController on
>   app.SayHiViewController: 0x2f3dw1009h00> whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

Is there any specific way to determine when the error took place and immediatetly represent the viewcontroller that was skipped?

This code normally works fine, the error only occurs when the user dismisses many different view controllers fast.

```
   func load(viewController : UIViewController) {

 if let presentedViewController = viewController.presentedViewController {
              present(fromRootViewController: presentedViewController)

            } else if let secondPresentedVC = viewController.presentedViewController?.presentedViewController {

                present(fromRootViewController: secondPresentedVC)

            } else if let topMostViewController = viewController.presentedViewController?.presentedViewController?.presentedViewController {
              present(fromRootViewController: topMostViewController)

            } else {
                present(fromRootViewController: viewController)
            }



 }
```